# How do I reference a dependent project built with a different configuration in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, build-dependencies

I have two Xcode projects: `Super` and `Sub`. `Super` has a custom configuration: `Enterprise`. `Sub` only has the default configurations: `Debug` and `Release`. `Super` has a target dependency on `Sub`. When I build `Super` with the `Enterprise` configuration, `Sub` builds with its default configuration: `Release`. This yields the following hierarchy:

```
Build
|-Products
  |-Enterprise-iphoneos
    |-Super.app
  |-Release-iphoneos
    |-libSub.a
    |-Sub
      |-Sub.h
```

Clang fails to build because `libSub.a` and `Sub/Sub.h` is normally in the same directory as `Super.app`, but instead is in a different directory because `Sub` built with the `Release` configuration instead of `Enterprise`. I control both projects, so I could easily add an `Enterprise` configuration to `Sub`, but I feel like there must be a magical incantation of [Xcode Build Settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) to make this work.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I've been hacking about with the same issues. And not just with my own library projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved exactly the same problem by using Xcode Configuration Files in my parent project - typically your application.

These are the steps I took:

1. Create a Base Configuration file in Xcode via New > Other > Configuration File.
2. Write your base `xcconfig` file, mine looks a bit like this:

   ```
   /// Configure Search Paths
   HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/usr/local/include"
   LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(SRCROOT)/../Externals/Libraries/GoogleAnalytics"

   /// Linker flags
   OTHER_LDFLAGS=-ObjC -all_load
   ```
3. The thing to note here, is that `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)` is the concatenation of:

   ```
   $(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)-$(PLATFORM_NAME)
   ```
4. Write a specialised configuration for a custom configuration. I created an Ad Hoc configuration which duplicated Release, therefore my search paths now look like this:

   ```
   #include "BaseConfig.xcconfig"

   /// Ad Hoc search paths
   HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(BUILD_DIR)/Release-$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILD_DIR)/Release-$(PLATFORM_NAME)/usr/local/include"
   LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(BUILD_DIR)/Release-$(PLATFORM_NAME)" "$(SRCROOT)/../Externals/Sources/GoogleAnalytics"
   ```

Then in your application's project's Info tab select your configurations, to use the Base Configuration for Debug and Release, and then the special one for your custom configuration.

Comment: Thanks! I just wish there was a cleaner way.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this will work when it comes to Archiving! Arrg!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in one of my apps. In Xcode 12.4 I was able to solve it by setting the **System Framework Search Paths** for my extra configuration (which I call Ad Hoc for Test) to `$(BUILD_DIR)/Release$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)`.

This setting can be found in your project by selecting your Target and then the Build Settings tab. I suggest searching for "System Framework" to find it. Once you add the path, Xcode will translate it to the actual path on your system, as seen in my screenshot. This works for archiving too.

[image: Build Settings Example]