# Xcode "Embed Frameworks" built under different configuration

Tags: ios, xcode

In addition to the standard "Release" and "Debug" configurations, an app I develop has an "Adhoc" configuration, used for ad-hoc testing builds. The frameworks built alongside it in the workspace do not have this configuration, because their behavior is not customized for ad-hoc builds. Therefore, when the workspace builds for ad-hoc, the products are separated into:

- `$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR` (which has an `Adhoc` prefix)
- `$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/../Release-iphoneos` or `$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/../Release-iphonesimulator`, depending on which we are currently building for.

It's easy enough to get this working with library and framework search paths, by adding `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../Release-$(PLATFORM_NAME)` to those settings. At this point, my app builds correctly, but fails on the "Embed Frameworks" step.

My frameworks are added to the app project with the location `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR` and a relative path of just their name.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347875/how-do-i-reference-a-dependent-project-built-with-a-different-configuration-in-x) is similar, but it only works for static libraries, which do not require this step - I'm using frameworks.

If there is a better way to handle this, please let me know - but I don't want to push the custom configuration upwards into the frameworks, because some of them may be eventually be open-sourced, and details of our internal process are irrelevant in that case.

Comment: Why does the Ad-Hoc setup need to be any different than Release? The only thing that might change is you might use a different signing profile?

Comment: Including the HockeyApp framework, `#if` code for setting that up, dev-only features, etc.

Comment: Will this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523690/xcode-custom-build-configuration-causes-library-file-not-found-for-static-libr) help?

Comment: No - that is for static libraries. I have vaguely solved this by adding a script that checks the configuration and does `cp -R "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../Release-$(PLATFORM_NAME)"/*.framework "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"`, and it works, but I'm not sure that it's really _correct_.

Comment: I used the same script. Not sure if it is correct, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in one of my apps. In Xcode 12.4 I was able to solve it by setting the **System Framework Search Paths** for my Ad Hoc configuration to `$(BUILD_DIR)/Release$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)`.

This setting can be found in your project by selecting your Target and then the Build Settings tab. I suggest searching for "System Framework" to find it. Once you add the path, Xcode will translate it to the actual path on your system, as seen in my screenshot.

[image: Build Settings Example]